# Vba changing pivottable filter value from user form error

Tags: excel, vba

i have userform and need when changing value in user form to change a value in the pivottable ( day ) Filter and make it = x .

i tried the below code but it show me error

```
ComboBox1 = Format(ComboBox1, "dd""-""mm""-""yyyy")
Dim pt As PivotTable
 Dim pvFld As PivotField
 Dim x As Date
 
 x = Me.ComboBox1.Text
   
With Worksheets("print").PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("date")
    .ClearAllFilters
    .CurrentPage = x
    
End With
```

Comment: Example in my side : pf date number format is `[$-409]dd-mmm-yy;@`. x value is a string like this `01-01-2023` (dd-mm-yyyy). So I convert the x to follow the pf date number format, but using slash ---> `x = Format(x, "dd\/mmm\/yy")` ---> x in Locals window show  `01/Jan/23`. Then the `.CurrentPage = x` work in my side. If I have pf date number format with `dd-mmm-yy` it won't work. I have to format the pf date with the $ and the @ sign ---> `[$-409]dd-mmm-yy;@` or just choose the available item in the list which show `14-Mar-01` (the second one). Tested in Excel 2010.

Comment: i will try do this